# Foundation 5: Grid inside tab

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

I want to build a complex form which uses Foundation 5 tabs and grids, and I find that the grids act weirdly. Here is the code:

```
<dl class="tabs" data-tab>
    <dd class="active"><a href="#panel_a">Subform A</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#panel_b">Subform B</a></dd>
</dl>
<div class="tabs-content">
    <div class="content active" id="panel_a">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
            <input type="text" id="field1" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <label for="select1">Select 1</label>
            <select id="select1">
                ...
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="panel_b">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <label for="field2">Field 2</label>
            <input type="text" id="field2" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code, the grids `large-6` act weirdly with the input field is skewed to the left. Can anybody suggest a fix on this? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the text feild and the select box on the same line? 
You need to add small-6 to each large-6 like so:

```
    <dl class="tabs" data-tab>
        <dd class="active"><a href="#panel_a">Subform A</a>

        </dd>
        <dd><a href="#panel_b">Subform B</a>

        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div class="tabs-content">
        <div class="content active" id="panel_a">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="large-6 small-6 columns">
                    <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
                    <input type="text" id="field1" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="large-6 small-6 columns">
                    <label for="select1">Select 1</label>
                    <select id="select1">...</select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="panel_b">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <label for="field2">Field 2</label>
                    <input type="text" id="field2" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Or maybe inline labels?
Here is a fiddle with both examples, hope this helps.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/defonic/5szAV/